# rendered viewport not showing objects, rendered image works fine

Tags: cycles-render-engine

The render preview in cycles shows nothing but overlays. So I can see outlines, emptys, the camera... but not the actual objects, materials, light... .

[image]

When I render an image every thing seems right. Its is only the the viewport and it is not the clipping border. The problem is only in cycles, eevee works fine.

I use Blender 2.83. Here is the [blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15z4_9nThO3P23k4qyk_B63yZ_uoq7FsH/view?usp=sharing).

I am lost and can't work that way. Please, does someone know what to do?

Comment: I'm guessing you have an AMD GPU and have recently updated drivers? This is a very common issue recently. The best solution is to roll back to an earlier driver version. If you do not have an AMD GPU, do the opposite, and update your drivers,

Comment: Possibly your viewport renderer is paused, the button in the top right.

Comment: It was the pause, thanks Allen.I didn't know about that